# Dynamic Parition

Tags: hadoop, hive

The following code does not work while working with multiple dynamic partition

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true; 
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

---

```
Insert Into TABLE CDR PARTITION  (Trandate_date,Transaction_Type )   
Select a.*,a.TransType AS Transaction_Name from CDR a;
```

Comment: what does not work exactly

Comment: shouldn't this `TransType AS Transaction_Name` be `TransType AS Transaction_Type`, just the arrow in the dark

Comment: You're reading and writing into same table. I doubt that is allowed. Try inserting into new table and make sure column names match in partition and select query. 

`insert into table t1 partition (col1,col2,col3) select c1 as col1, c2 as col2, c3 as col3 from t2`